# Ruby's times method and for loop does the same thing, but what are the respective processes?

Tags: ruby

I have a paradigm where the purpose is to calculate "the total accumulated from 'variable from' to 'variable to'". I got two methods, but I don't know exactly what steps they go through.

The first is the times method. I don't understand what (to - from +1) produces and why (i + from)?  Also, this code throws syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input, I don't know where I am going wrong .

```
from = 10
to = 20
sum = 0
  (to - from +1).times to |i|
    sum = sum + (i + from)
  end
puts sum
```

Then there is the for loop. I can't understand what is the "total sum accumulated from 'variable from' to 'variable to'", what is the process of adding it?

```
from = 10
to = 20
sum = 0
for i in from..to
  sum = sum + i
end
puts sum
```

I'm bad at math, thank you all.

Comment: It should be `times do |i|` notice `do` vs `to`

Comment: It's a sum of all numbers from `from` to `to`. And there is a much nicer way to achieve it in Ruby `(10..20).sum` or `(from..to).sum`

Comment: You may be bad at maths, but I'm sure you can work out what `20 - 10 + 1` is.

Comment: @TomLord It works, but I don't know why

Comment: @TPR: sounds like it's time for tracing the program with a pen and paper. Pretend you're the computer and run the program in your head line by line, writing down values for variables after every instruction.

Comment: @Tom, according to my HP 35S that should be 11.

Comment: TPR, you don't need no stinkin' loops: `(from+to-1)*(to-from)/2 #=> 29*10/2 #=> 145`.

Comment: What would i be here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `IRB` you can create an array that represents all the numbers `from` to `to`:

```
irb(main):043:0> from=10
=> 10
irb(main):044:0> to=20
=> 20
irb(main):047:0> a=(from..to).to_a
=> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

You can get a `sum` of that array:

```
irb(main):048:0> a.sum
=> 165
```

And, actually, you don't need to make an array at all:

```
irb(main):049:0> (from..to).sum
=> 165
```

---

Side note. If you have three dots the last value of `to` is not included and that is a different sum obviously:

```
irb(main):053:0> (from...to).to_a
=> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
irb(main):054:0> (from...to).sum
=> 145
```

So `upto` should *really* be called `uptoandincluding`:

```
irb(main):055:0> from.upto(to).to_a
=> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

You can also use `reduce` or the alias `inject` either with a block or symbol to an operation to reduct a list the the pairwise application of the operator.

Example (`reduce` and `inject` are the same, but I usually use inject with a block or reduce with the parenthesis):

```
# block form where n is repeatedly added to an accumulator
irb(main):058:0> (from..to).inject{|sum, n| sum+n}
=> 165

# the operator + is repeated applied from the left to right 
irb(main):059:0> (from..to).reduce(:+)
=> 165
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few idiomatic ways of solving this problem in Ruby. They might be a little easier to follow than the solution you proposed.

```
sum = 0

10.upto(20) do |i|
  sum = sum + i
end
```

For the first iteration of loop, i will = `10`, the second, i will =  `11` and so "up to" `20`.  Each time it will add the value of `i` to `sum`. When it completes, `sum` will have a value of `165`.

Another way is this:

```
10.upto(20).sum
```

The reason this works is that `10.upto(20)` returns an `Enumerator`. You can call `sum` on an `Enumerator`.